# How to parse text in the input?

Tags: reactjs

I need to parse the text that is put in the input by user, so that I could form component with words related to the specific word.

Example: i need* to buy dog*

The words that end with * are needed to be found in the text and send to server to get the response with the related words.

All this process should start by pressing the button 'Обучить'.

I tried to do parsing but I am worried that it would be unstable if there are more than one user in the system.

Code of the component with text field and button is here:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // initial state
    this.state = {
        textInput: '',
        text: ''
    }

}

clear = () => {
    // return the state to initial
    this.setState({
        textInput: ''
    })
}

write = () => {
    this.setState(
        {
            text:''
        }
    )
}

render(){
    return (
        <Paper style={{maxWidth: 936, marginLeft: '250px', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
            <AppBar position="static" color="default" elevation={0}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Grid container spacing={16} alignItems="center">
                        <Grid item xs>
                            <TextField
                                fullWidth
                                placeholder="Введите фразу которую нужно обучить"
                                id = 'textInput'
                                InputProps={{
                                    disableUnderline: true,
                                }}
                                value={this.state.textInput}
                                onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({textInput: e.target.value})}}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #00ACD3 30%, #00BE68 90%)'}}>
                                Обучить
                            </Button>
                            <Tooltip title="Сбросить">
                                <IconButton>
                                    <RefreshIcon color="inherit" style={{display: 'block'}} id = 'clearButton' onClick={this.clear}/>
                                </IconButton>
                            </Tooltip>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <div style={{margin: '40px 16px'}}>
                <Typography color="textSecondary" align="center">
                    Пока ничего не было обучено
                </Typography>
            </div>
        </Paper>
    );
}
```

Ideally I want to get the ability to somehow find words like this and save them to be send on the server.

Comment: Hi, // it would be unstable if there are more than one user in the system// - is it means concurrent user using the server?

Comment: Yes, do you have any ideas on how to make it stable?

Comment: The unstable issue is not due to front-end.Please share more details about the backend and how you search/process data in backend.

Comment: On backend there is just API call to the system that picks up words based on the word send to it. The return is in json format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a filterArray, then update it based on textInput endsWith '*',
 i have updated this solution,

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        // initial state
        this.state = {
            textInput: '',
            text: '',
            filterArray: []
        }
    }

    clear = () => {
        // return the state to initial
        this.setState({
            textInput: ''
        })
    }

    write = () => {
        this.setState(
            {
                text:''
            }
        )
    }

    changeHandler = (event) => {
        let textInput = event.target.value;
        if(textInput !== ''){
            let tempArray = textInput.split(" ");// `convert string into array`
            let filterArray = tempArray.filter(word => word.endsWith('*'));
            this.setState({textInput, filterArray});    
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <Paper style={{maxWidth: 936, marginLeft: '250px', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
                <AppBar position="static" color="default" elevation={0}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Grid container spacing={16} alignItems="center">
                            <Grid item xs>
                                <TextField
                                    fullWidth
                                    placeholder="Введите фразу которую нужно обучить"
                                    id = 'textInput'
                                    InputProps={{
                                        disableUnderline: true,
                                    }}
                                    value={this.state.textInput}
                                    onChange={(e)=>{this.changeHandler(e)}}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #00ACD3 30%, #00BE68 90%)'}}>
                                    Обучить
                                </Button>
                                <Tooltip title="Сбросить">
                                    <IconButton>
                                        <RefreshIcon color="inherit" style={{display: 'block'}} id = 'clearButton' onClick={this.clear}/>
                                    </IconButton>
                                </Tooltip>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <div style={{margin: '40px 16px'}}>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary" align="center">
                        Пока ничего не было обучено
                    </Typography>
                </div>
            </Paper>
        );
    }
```

After getting filterArray with '*' data, iterate using forEach(), then pass to response API.

Comment: There is problem that the first symbol is not allowed to be deleted with delete button after adding your code

Comment: @SashaSedova where is delete button in above code i just added one extra state. Please provide delete button code as well.

Comment: I mean delete button on the keyboard of computer